# How can I get a divided value resulting from 2 summed fields in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public partial class MemberTank
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TankName { get; set; }
    public int Battles { get; set; }
    public int Victories { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to construct a LINQ that gets me a list of TankName with the victory percentage of each tank.  I know I need to divide the sums of both battles and victories but I'm not sure how to do that.

Doing the sum of one or the other is easy ...

```
 var sumVictories = (from p in db.MemberTanks
                     group p by p.TankName into g
                     select new { 
                         Tank = g.Key, 
                         Victories = g.Sum(p => p.Victories) 
                     }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Victories);
```

... but I'm not sure how to make it sum both fields then divide them to get the percentage I need.

Comment: can there be multiple MemberTank instances with same TankName?

Comment: Yes. (I know, the data is a little abnormal... not much I can do about that though)

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
        var sumVictories = (from p in memberTanks
                            group p by p.TankName
                            into g
                            select new
                                    {

                                        Tank = g.Key,
                                        Victories = g.Sum(p => p.Victories),
                                        Avg = ((double)g.Sum(p => p.Victories) / (double)g.Sum(p => p.Battles)) * 100
                                    }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Victories);
```

[edit] Cleaned the code up a little